# How to create a closure for a variable in C#?

Tags: c#, closures

The following example prints the number "5" five times after 1 second.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    EasyTimer.SetTimeout(() => Console.WriteLine(i), 1000);
}
```

(Assume `EasyTime.SetTimeout` behaves like JavaScript's `setTimeout`)

How can we create a closure around `i` such that it keeps it remembers its value for the callback?

I know [how to do it in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5606076/65387) but I'm not sure if we can do it the same way in C#.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inside the block, assign i to a new variable j, and use j in the lambda, as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    int j = i;
    EasyTimer.SetTimeout(() => Console.WriteLine(j), 1000);
}
```

Notably, this issue only crops up because the lambda *is* a closure over `i`, so it gets the value when the lambda executes, not when it's created.

Comment: Simpler than I was thinking. Thanks!

Comment: If I understand correctly, in C# `for{}` blocks create a new scope, whereas in more dynamic languages like JavaScript and Python they do not? I get confused after working in too many languages :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using C#5.0 you can write the following:

```
foreach (int i in Enumerable.Range(0, 5))
{
    EasyTimer.SetTimeout(() => Console.WriteLine(i), 1000);
}
```

It will automatically generate local variable. This will only work in foreach loop, not for.